# How do you change the storage driver Window uses for booting?

Tags: ssd, hibernate, windows-10-v2004

In the past, my laptop used "storahci" to boot from a SATA SSD, but after cloning to an NVMe drive, it stopped recognizing the NVMe SDD because it was using a SATA driver (storahci), but after using `sc.exe config stornvme start= boot`, a command to change drivers used at startup from cold bootup, it changed to use (stornvme) to correctly boot using the new NVMe drive. But because of this, hibernation is completely broken. It just throws the laptop into sleep mode, without properly dumping memory to disk and powering off. How do I fix this?

Does this have to do with Windows using Winload from a shutdown, and using Winresume from a hibernate, since Winload is now configured correctly to use "stornvme" on NVMe, but winresume still uses "storachi" on NVMe and not SATA?

Comment: I’m not sure whether resuming uses any drivers at all, or if it relies on BIOS (INT 13h) or UEFI services to access storage. // Perhaps try turning hibernate off and on again using `powercfg`.

Comment: Yeah, using powercfg.exe /hibernate off and then using powercfg.exe /hibernate on just made hibernate a sleep button. I think I did try that yesterday.